# sqlite returns only one record 

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios4

I have done the method to fetch the subcategories based on given main category id.

When running this method, it does fetch the only one record. i mean the control comes to

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
```

`while` loop only once.

When executing the same query into the sql browser it works fine and fetches the results as expected.I don't know why this not working when running the function

Please let me know, what the problem lies over the code below

```
- ( NSMutableDictionary * ) getDataToDisplayTierTwo:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)iD{        
    NSMutableDictionary *aTierTwoData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from sub_categories_reference scr inner join sub_categories ssc on ssc.id = scr.sub_category_id where  scr.main_category_id = %@ ",iD];    
        const char *sql_query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];            
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;           
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {               
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSLog(@"coming insode");
                NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];                 
                NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];                    
                [aTierTwoData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];
                [aValue release];
                [aId release];                  
                NSLog(@"%@ %@ ^^^^^^^^picker value id ", aValue, aId);
            }
        }
    }   
    else{
        //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to 
        sqlite3_close(database); 
    }        
    return aTierTwoData;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- ( NSMutableArray * ) getDataToDisplayTierTwo:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)iD{ 

NSMutableDictionary *aTierTwoData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *aTierArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 

{
    NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from sub_categories_reference scr inner join sub_categories ssc on ssc.id = scr.sub_category_id where  scr.main_category_id = %@ ",iD];    
    const char *sql_query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];            
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;           
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {               
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSLog(@"coming insode");
            NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];                 
            NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)]; 

             NSLog(@"%@ %@ ^^^^^^^^picker value id ", aValue, aId);                   
            [aTierTwoData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];
            [aValue release];
            [aId release];         

            [aTierArray addObject:aTierTwoData];   


             aTierTwoData = nil;

        }
    }
}   

else{
    //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to 
    sqlite3_close(database); 
}        
return aTierArray;        
}
```